# Função Javascript não roda Online

Tags: javascript

O código abaixo só funciona em localhost , online não funciona, isto é, funciona perfeitamente na minha máquina, quando transfiro para o servidor , nada disso funciona, ja quebrei a cabeça e não consegui solucionar.

**DETALHE!** - O `arquivo.js` esta dentro do diretório raiz do `http://loacalhost` sem caminhos intermediarios, observe:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="arquivo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/arquivo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../arquivo.js"></script>
```

Realizei testes local, com os três tipos citados acima e todos se saíram bem. Já no *servidor* `http://xpg.uol.com.br` tenho feito da mesma maneira deixando-o na raiz, porém sem sucesso.

Numa nova tentativa, fiz a inclusão do conteúdo do `arquivo.js` dentro do documento HTML(página `index.html`), mesmo assim, sem chance.

Em outra tentativa com **caminho absoluto**, relativos a configuração do servidor, sendo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://meusite.xpg.uol.com.br/arquivo.js"></script>
```

.. funfa legal quando posto em `localhost` caso contrário ... nem pensar.

Enfim, me parece estar no escopo da função ou até mesmo na colocação da mesma na página.

Gostaria de entender onde estou errando. Agradeço desde ja, ajuda de todos.

Comment: Tem a ver com os caminhos relativos e configuração do servidor, para resolver isso use caminho absoluto, isto é: www.meusite.pt/public/js/bootstrap.js

Comment: Como fica a url em produção do import?

Comment: Ola, Em colocar na mesma pasta da pagina e usar <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="arquivo.js"></script> não funciona? qual é o erro no console?

Comment: Se estiver usando o Chrome, aperte F12 e veja se tem uma bolinha com um 'x' branco mostrando que tem erros, clique nele e diga o que aparece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A todos que comentaram em suma resposta à pergunta, cheguei a conclusão. Foi preciso alterar as seguintes linhas:

**errado** `onclick="nome(txt)"`

retirei o `txt` não era necessário fazer referência ao `<input type="text" id="txt"/>`, e ficou assim:

`onclick="nome()"`

também:

**errado** `document.all.id.value;`

que agora, esta escrito assim:

`document.getElementById('id').value;`

> Pronto!
>
> Por motivos que desconheço, depois de modificar, a **Função Javascript** passou a funcionar tanto no lado *Cliente* quanto no lado *Sevidor.*